# FLOT chart date and time on x-axis

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm using flot charts. I want to show date and time on x-axis.
Here is my code:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
    xaxis: {
      mode: "time", 
      timeformat:"%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"        
    },
});
```

In the graph on x-axis shown as `14/07/15 00:00:00`. Time is not displayed.

Answer (score 9):

*Answer edited after understanding what the problem is:*

The ticks on the x axis are not where your data points are (unless you use the `ticks` option) but are evenly spaced over the range of your time values. If your data ranges over several days there will be only one tick per day and that tick will be at midnight.

To change this behaviour you can use the `tickSize` option with something like

```
tickSize: [4, 'hour']
```

to generate a tick every 4 hours.

See [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) and [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data) for more info in the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md).

Comment: @user3514944 See my edit. I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It's `tickSize` not `ticksize`.

Comment: ok, I changed to tickSize but it is changing in the date only not in time format.It still shows time as 00:00

Comment: With `tickSize: [4, 'hours']` and a wider placeholder div I get this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zTJA5.png which shows the expected results